# Bash - remove whole content of file starting from specific string

Tags: bash, macos, sed

I have in a yml file a string containing: `# base config`. Now I want to remove everything from this file starting from this specific string. I want to remove this string, too. Is there a command for it?

### bash file

```
for filename in ./config/*.yml; do
    if grep -qxF "# base config" $filename
    then
        echo "has base config, will replace it"
        sed -i "" "# base config/q" $filename # this does not do anything
    else
        echo "has NOT base config, will add it"
        cat $base_config >> $filename
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With sed:

```
sed -n '/#base config/q;p' file
```

Or with awk:

```
awk '/#base config/{exit};1' file
```

So you may replace the sed line in your script by these two:

```
sed -n '/#base config/q;p' "$filename" > tmpfile
mv tmpfile "$filename"
```

Notice I double-quoted the variable, that's good practice.

Comment: Very nice, that's it!